# Finding count using if conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to achieve number of users in previous who have business value greater than 0 and giving two coniditions i.e. region & level of business but when I put the below formula it is calculating all users instead of giving me result basis on conditions.

`=IF($H$1="all",COUNTIF(F:F,H3),COUNTIFS(F:F,H3,E:E,$H$1,C:C,">0"))`

I am trying to achieve number of users in previous who have business value greater than 0 and giving two coniditions i.e. region & level of business but when I put the below formula it is calculating all users instead of giving me result basis on conditions.

Comment: Provide data sample.

Comment: Don't you want: `=IF($H$1="all",COUNTIFS(F:F,H3,C:C,">0"),COUNTIFS(F:F,H3,E:E,$H$1,C:C,">0"))`

Comment: Organisation ID name                      FY22 FY23 Region Segment
0010X00004sdLT4 New convent school 0 125196.5 NORTH India -Level 3

Comment: @Rory it helped, thnx, but its not given count if used other region, suppose "east, west..."